# Workflow for editing content?

Tags: workflow, plone

A client wants to be able to approve changes made to content after they have been edited by a user with an editor role. In that once the editor makes the change they want to be able to approve the change before it is published.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this before with Working Copy Support. It's part of plone core but not installed by default.

This will give you a checkout action button(and check in). There are different permissions you can assign to various roles to allow check outs but not checkins and such.

You may have to customize a workflow's permissions to get it just the way you want but it's doable with out-of-the-box plone

Comment: +1 for this answer, also you probably need to customize permission for performing "check-in".

Comment: You will definitely need to customize the check-in permissions, but, yes this is the purpose of working copies.  You will also likely want to use content rules to create appropriate notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this wat the Simple Publication Workflow (editors submit for review, reviewers approve and publish or send back the changes) is for?